# A definition of arithmetic divisor with conic singularities?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities, kahler-einstein-metric

I have a question related to the preprint ["Heights and metrics with logarithmic singularities" by G. Freixas i Montplet](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~vincent.maillot/Arakelov/0038/).

Let $X$ be an arithmetic variety with arithmetic divisor $D$ how can we introduce an arithmetic divisor with conic singularities?
Here is [the definition of conical singularities on a Kähler variety](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5013v1)

I am looking for an arithmetic version.

If an arithmetic variety be of general type can we say $Ric(\omega)=-\omega$ on $X(\mathbb C)$ ? What about the definition of Kähler-Einstein metric on arithmetic varieties? When does it exist?

Comment: I wonder, what is the interest in conic singularities in the arithmetic world? They are useful for continuity methods in Kaehler geometry.

Comment: see paper of Odaka about arithmetic canonical metric

Comment: He just mentions that one could extend the theory, he does not motivate why one would be interested.

Comment: Actually I am readding  the paper of Odaka and I faced with this question